# R cannot be resolved at android 4.2.2 properties

Tags: java, android, opencv

I got **`R cannot be resolved`** a variable error when i debug with build target at *android 4.2.2*, in addition when i debug with *android 5.1.1*, i got cannot load library error. How can i solve these problems. Thanks for your helps.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final String imageInSD = "/sdcard/dapi1.jpg";   


    Mat src,dst;
    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        //Mat image = Highgui.imread(imageInSD);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
        Size size = new Size(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        src = new Mat(size,CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,src);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.threshold(src, src, 100, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C);
        Utils.matToBitmap(src, bitmap);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using eclipse then switch to android studio first

Comment: yes, i am using eclipse if i cannot solve the errors i will. thanks

Comment: you will have a bad time porting opencv support to idea... I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is deprecated. You should use [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html). Your android 5.1.1 supports AppCompatActivity.Please try with AppCompatActivity .Let me inform works or not .

Comment: i tried AppCompatActivity and i got "cannot load library" and "native method not  found" errors.

Comment: If you are  using Android Studio then properly import  R or opencv files

Comment: Okay, Clean and Rebuild your Project

Comment: If above tricks not works please post your total code.For your kind advice moved to Android Studio.Eclipse is dead

Comment: i will try to move android studio. thanks for help. Actually my total code is above. Do you want to see .xml files?

Comment: i setup the android studio, do you have any advices for importing opencv?